# iPhone is it is possible to find the limit of a UILabel?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, text, uilabel

Is there any way to find the text limit of UILabel? I just wanted to find when the text limit of the UILabel exceeds. Like the Xcode identifies the line break of a Label. Is it is possible?

Comment: I don't think there's simply a way. Easiest thing to do is paste like 500 characters in, and then copy the ones that show in the label, and then take that to a character counter, likely easily available with Google, and then it will give you a count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for the `sizeWithFont:` method:

```
float textWidth = [yourString sizeWithFont:yourLabel.font].width;
```

Then compare `textWidth` with `yourLabel.bounds.size.width`.

Answer (score 0):

technically the `UILabel`'s text property is an `NSString` object, and for the `NSString` object **there is no known limitation of length** but the memory.

Comment: addition info from our office: some programmers (don't ask the reason!) loaded 15MB into the `NSString` but the largest text was 48MB in a simple `NSString`.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare width of label with width of text. You can get the size of text with sizeWithFont method of NSString. For font you can use label.font.